# How to block all connections on domain controller except one computer in domain

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2008-r2, domain

I want to block all connections in windows firewall on domain controller except computers in domain and allow domain clients only exchange files in one location by one program (total commander)
How i can do that, what type of exception i have to add to firewall?

Comment: What connections do you want to block?  Why do you want users to only make use of Total Commander?

Comment: I want to block ALL connections on domain controller except file sharing from one folder for computers in domain. And i want to client use one program (all other programs should be blocked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly you want users to be able to make use of one folder to exchange files.  You will first need to disable file sharing on the users workstations.  This can be done by setting up a Group Policy on the domain controller.  Navigate to
User Configuration –> Policies –> Administrative Templates –> Windows Components
Expand Windows Components, look for Network Sharing.

This how to will show you how to do this:  [GPO setup](http://win7filesharing.blogspot.com/)

Users now cannot share folders on their workstations. They can only use the shared folder that you have created for them, by either using Total Commander or Windows Explorer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to block all connections comming to domain controller except file sharing. I started with IP security policies, added ip filter to block all connections except ips that i add manually, i turned on a firewall and disabled all policies (dns and file sharing is on), now i want to block all applications except windows explorer or totalcommander. What i should add?

Comment: Have a look in Group Policy. You can restrict the use of some programs with a GPO.  [link]http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323525